# Totalling values until I get to a certain point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to do the following:

1. Order records by `DIVLOC` and the `DISTRIB` with highest values
2. Then sum up the `DISTRIB` for each `DIVLOC` until it reaches >=.60
3. Turn the `ETAFLAG = 1` for these records that make up the 60 for each `DIVLOC`

So for my results example below at the bottom

```
-- --Create Fake table 
DECLARE @ETATRACTS TABLE (DIVLOC int, TRACTID int, Distrib float, ETAFLAG bit)

INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71001, 1123, .30, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71001, 1010, .20, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71001, 3010, .10, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71001, 0790, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71001, 6010, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71250, 3010, .40, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71250, 0610, .10, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71250, 3210, .10, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71250, 1920, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71250, 9720, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71250, 2110, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .20, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .20, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .05, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .01, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .01, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .01, 0)
INSERT INTO @ETATRACTS VALUES (71425, 5011, .01, 0)

UPDATE @ETATRACTS
SET ETAFLAG = t.ETAFLAG
FROM @ETATRACTS AS temptable, 
     (SELECT 
          DIVLOC, TRACTID, Distrib,
          (CASE WHEN SUM(Distrib) OVER (PARTITION BY divloc) - Distrib >= 0.2
                 THEN 1
           END) AS ETAFLAG
       FROM @ETATRACTS) AS t
WHERE 
    temptable.divloc = t.DIVLOC AND temptable.TRACTID = t.TRACTID

SELECT * FROM @ETATRACTS
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlB9V.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `select` query for this:

```
select e.*,
       (case when sum(Distrib) over (partition by divloc order by Distrib desc) - Distrib < 0.6
             then 1 else 0
        end) as ETAFLAG
from @ETATRACTS e;
```

This logic can easily be put into an `update`:

```
with toupdate (
      select e.*,
             (case when sum(Distrib) over (partition by divloc order by Distrib desc) - Distrib < 0.6
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as new_ETAFLAG
      from @ETATRACTS e
     )
update toupdate
    set new_ETAFLAG = ETAFLAG;
```

Comment: It is so stupid but when I run this code you are proposing I get this error:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: @Bearcatrunner . . . All supported versions of SQL Server support cumulative sums.  You may be using an unsupported version or have the compatibility set to an earlier version.